# Is there any software that can be used for positional chess training?

Tags: engines, software, positional-play

I am looking for a software that would help me in improving my positional chess understanding. Is there any such software or website?

Comment: A few days ago, my answer received a question in a comment that was apparently intended to be a question-comment here.  Perhaps you could answer it for Yobamamama: "Why not books? Do you need software or just prefer it?".  Thanks in advance!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an engine something like [Chess Position Trainer](http://www.chesspositiontrainer.com/index.php/en/), depending upon your requirements (and system).
     There is some potential for an unexpected [learning curve](https://www.chess.com/download/view/chess-position-trainer), at least within version 5.04.
     That being said, it is noted as working in both [Windows](http://www.chesspositiontrainer.com/index.php/en/cpt-kunena-forum/10-general/184-windows-10-and-cpt) & [Linux](https://www.chess.com/blog/SamCopeland/the-best-linux-apps-for-chess).

[Komodo 8](http://en.chessbase.com/post/hartmann-choosing-a-chess-engine) also gets some recommendation.

[Chessimo](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/positional-play-puzzle-bookssoftware) has at least one detractor, who showed a preference for [Convekta](http://www.convekta.com/download.htm), this latter offering both downloadable and online games (their [online play](http://chessok.com/?page_id=145) permits Windows, iOS, Android, & Web Interface).

[Basic Positional Ideas](http://www.chesscentral.com/basic-positional-ideas-download/) "...*is a supplementary program [that] can only be run if [*sic*] [Fritz](http://shop.chessbase.com/en/products/fritz_15_english?Ref=RF70-5OH0EFN840) 8*...". The description indicates that the program is for learning "...*[how] to achieve the desired position on your board*...".
     The use of Fritz indicates that it should run on Windows, but that you might [need Wine](http://www.calmar.ws/div/fritz_and_wine.html) in order to run it within a Linux environment.

Comment: Why not books?   Do you need software or just prefer it?

Comment: @yobamamama Although I edited the original question, and submitted this answer, I'm not the question's originator (that would be Prakhar Londhe); perhaps asking this as a comment to the question itself would be best.   :-)

Comment: I thought I did comment on the question.